# Library for viewing logs inside my java web app

Tags: java, logging, web

I found the following question that is relatively close to what I want : [view log in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369700/is-there-a-way-to-view-my-web-apps-tomcat-logs-in-a-browser-real-time). 
I want also to view my logs, but to have options for filtering and customizing the view. The filtering is the most important feature. 
For example I specify the format of my log row ( time-user-type-message ) and then filter the rows by time or by user. Has anyone heard for such library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash, elasticsearch and Kibana [Combination of these three will provide what you want]

refer this tut :http://logstash.net

and for integrating the above tools : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04